# ASUS motherboard keeps restarting, CPU and DRAM POST LEDs flashing

Tags: motherboard, post

Seeking help for motherboard **ASUS ROG Strix z370-e gaming**, which suddenly stopped working. Just to be clear, this is not a new build - my PC has been working flawlessly for a long time and last hardware component upgrade was months ago, so this is totally out of the blue. What I get when I power it up is:

- Power on LED is up.
- Starts POST normally, fans start working, logo on the side of the video card lights up.
- Then in quick succession, **yellow and red LEDs go up and down** (those are AFAIK, CPU and DRAM LEDs)
- At this point the motherboard powers off for ~3s, then the whole process repeats.
- Power button no longer is able to turn it off, I have to unplug the power cable.

The manual says "If an error is found the critical component LED stays lit up until the problem is resolved." In my case they just flash and torn off (until the process repeats).

Anyone seen something similar? I'd rather avoid the guessing game of buying and trying replacement component blindly... Any help would be greatly appreciated! :(

**UPDATE:** reseated DRAM, took out video card and the motherboard seems to POST now. When I put the card back, it still POSTs but displays a message on screen: **Please power down and connect the PCIe cables for this graphics card** (the cables are obviously plugged in). Does it mean my power supply is faulty?

Answer (score 1):

Reseated the power supply cables all around and the computer got back to normal. Oh well...